# Add bold into JavaScript Column

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I try to add bold only for part of the string.
But when I use that getElementByID and put the bold tags as a string in FE it returns it to me

> [object HTMLSpanElement]

[image]

```js
var boldSign = document.getElementById('boldSign');
boldSign.innerHTML = "<b>(+)</b>";
return {
  column: {name: boldSign+ " All other products"},
  addFilter: function () {
    vm.displayAll(!vm.displayAll())
  }
}
```

```html
<tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns, css: {highlighted: highlighted}">
  <td data-bind=" click: $parent.addFilter">
    <span style='white-space: pre-wrap;' id="boldSign" data-bind="text: $parent[propertyName] ? ($parent[propertyName].value ? $parent[propertyName].value : $parent[propertyName]) : ''"></span>
    <!-- ko if: $parent[propertyName] && $parent[propertyName].value -->
    <div data-bind="css: { 'positive-growth': $parent[propertyName].isPositive, 'negative-growth': !$parent[propertyName].isPositive }"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Looks like you're rendering text (`textContent`) rather than HTML (`innerHTML`).

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, if I put  boldSign.textContent + " All other products"
it returns that (+) to me but not bolded

Comment: I am referring to the internal renderer of Knockout.

Comment: understand.. and this can be fixed somehow..?

Answer (score 1):

### The problem: you can't `+` an HTML element and a string

The reason you're seeing `[object HTMLSpanElement] All other products`, is because you're adding an `HTMLSpanElement` to a `string`. Here's a reproduction taking knockout of of the equation:

```js
const mySpan = document.getElementById("mySpan");
const myString = " All other products";

console.log(
  mySpan + myString
);
```

```html
<span id="mySpan">( + )</span>
```

Javascript won't complain, but the result is probably not what you want!

It would make sense to use `innerHTML`, like you already did:

```js
const mySpan = document.getElementById("mySpan");
const myString = " All other products";

mySpan.innerHTML = `<b>${mySpan.innerHTML}</b> ${myString}`;
```

```html
<span id="mySpan">( + )</span>
```

### Working with knockout

When working with knockout, you should never be querying the document for HTML elements unless you're in a custom binding (which is already quite advanced).

Instead, you can create dynamic templates by using (among others) the `if`, `with` or `visible` bindings.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  rows: [
    { hasPlusSign: true, label: "Show all products" },
    { hasPlusSign: false, label: "Some product" }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: rows">
  <div>
    <span data-bind="if: hasPlusSign"><b>( + )</b></span>
    <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### The `html` binding

If you ever need to inject HTML strings in to your document when working with knockout (which is very rare), you'd have to use the `html` binding rather than the `text` binding.

You should never use the `html` binding unless you can absolutely 100% be sure that the HTML string you inject is safe.